# Email notification when comment form has been filled

Tags: facebook

I've created a comment form using PHP and MySQL table.  My question is, how do I make it so that when someone fills out the comment form it automatically sends me an email to notify me?

The code for the form is as below:

```
<?
@$todo=$_POST['todo'];
if(isset($todo) and $todo=="post_comment"){

$name=$_POST['name'];
$name=mysql_real_escape_string($name);
$email=$_POST['email'];
$email=mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$dtl=$_POST['dtl'];
$dtl=mysql_real_escape_string($dtl);

$status = "OK";
$msg="";

// if userid is less than 3 char then status is not ok
if( strlen($name) <3 or strlen($name) > 25){
$msg=$msg."Your name does not have sufficient characters.<BR>";
$status= "NOTOK";}                  

if( strlen($email) <7){
$msg=$msg."Please re-enter your email.<BR>";
$status= "NOTOK";}      

if( strlen($dtl) <6 ){
$msg=$msg."Your comment does not have sufficient characters.<BR>";
$status= "NOTOK";}                  
if($status<>"OK"){ 
echo "<font face='Verdana' size='2' color=red>$msg</font>";
}else{ // if all validations are passed.
$dt=date("Y-m-d"); 
$status='ns'; // Change this to apv if you want all messages to be automatically approved once posted.  
$query=mysql_query("insert into cmt_post(p_name,dt,name,email,dtl,status)
values('$p_name','$dt','$name','$email','$dtl','$status')");
echo mysql_error();
echo "<font face='Verdana' size='2' color='#333333'><b><br><br>Thank you for your post!  <br><br>
Your comment is waiting to be approved by Admin =) </b><br><br><br></font>";
//Send simple email
$to = "thefloatingorange@outlook.com;";
$from = "$email"; //Could be the person's email stored in a variable who is submitting the form
$subject = "Notification!"; //Your email subject

//Prepare your message. You can include sender's name and other detail
//stored in variables if you wish
$message = "Someone has posted a new comment.";

//Headers
$headers  = "From: $from\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

// now lets send the email
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

echo "Your message has been sent successfully.";

}
}// Checking of if condition if form is submittted
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

After successfully inserting the data in the table, you can use `mail()` function to send a notification.
Following is a simple demo of sending an email. While testing, make sure to check inside your junk folder if you don't receive the email.

```
//Send simple email

$to = "receiver@email.here";
$from = "sender@email.here"; //Could be the person's email stored in a variable who is submitting the form
$subject = "Notification!"; //Your email subject

//Prepare your message. You can include sender's name and other detail
//stored in variables if you wish
$message = "Someone has posted a new comment.";

//Headers
$headers  = "From: $from\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

// now lets send the email
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

echo "Your message has been sent successfully.";
```

This is how you should use mail() function with your code

```
@$todo=$_POST['todo'];
if(isset($todo) and $todo=="post_comment"){

$name=$_POST['name'];
$name=mysql_real_escape_string($name);
$email=$_POST['email'];
$email=mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$dtl=$_POST['dtl'];
$dtl=mysql_real_escape_string($dtl);

$status = "OK";
$msg="";

// if userid is less than 3 char then status is not ok
if( strlen($name) <3 or strlen($name) > 25){
$msg=$msg."Your name does not have sufficient characters.<BR>";
$status= "NOTOK";}                  

if( strlen($email) <7){
$msg=$msg."Please re-enter your email.<BR>";
$status= "NOTOK";}      

if( strlen($dtl) <6 ){
$msg=$msg."Your comment does not have sufficient characters.<BR>";
$status= "NOTOK";}                  



if($status<>"OK"){ 
echo "<font face='Verdana' size='2' color=red>$msg</font>";
}else{ // if all validations are passed.
$dt=date("Y-m-d"); 
$status='ns'; // Change this to apv if you want all messages to be automatically approved once
posted. 
$query=mysql_query("insert into cmt_post(p_name,dt,name,email,dtl,status)
values('$p_name','$dt','$name','$email','$dtl','$status')");
echo mysql_error();
echo "<font face='Verdana' size='2' color='#333333'><b><br><br>Thank you for your post!  <br><br>
Your comment is waiting to be approved by Admin =) </b><br><br><br></font>";

//Send simple email

$to = "thefloatingorange@outlook.com";
$from = $email; //Could be the person's email stored in a variable who is submitting the form
$subject = "Notification!"; //Your email subject

//Prepare your message. You can include sender's name and other detail
//stored in variables if you wish
$message = "Someone has posted a new comment.";

//Headers
$headers  = "From: $from\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

// now lets send the email
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

echo "Your message has been sent successfully.";

}
}// Checking of if condition if form is submittted
```

Comment: Thanks, Boshi. I added the email code after: 

if($status<>"OK"){ 
echo "<font face='Verdana' size='2' color=red>$msg</font>";

I changed the $to email to mine, which is thefloatingorange@outlook.com and $from="$email"

I am not getting any emails sent through though.  Have I inserted this incorrectly?

Comment: You have added the code where status is NOT equal to OK that means when there is some error captured. You should add it after inserting the data in the table. To be more precise, put email code after line: echo "<font face='Verdana' size='2' color='#333333'><b><br><br>Thank you for your post!  <br><br>
Your comment is waiting to be approved by Admin =) </b><br><br><br></font>";

Comment: Hi Boshi,  sorry, I'm still having trouble with this.  I have added the email form after the line that you have mentioned, however no emails are being sent.  The page that I am testing this on is "http://wwww.thefloatingorange.co.nf/1.php".  Is there something that is missing?  Thanks again.

Comment: I have added it to the code in the original post.  I must be doing something quite useless, my PHP is very very rusty!

Comment: Well, that's true :D!! You are pasting the code entirely outside it's scope. Just find this line  `Your comment is waiting to be approved by Admin =) </b><br><br><br></font>";` and put email code just after this.

Comment: Hi Boshi...Sorry!  I've tested it again, exactly as you said with the mail() function directly after **Admin =) </b><br><br><br></font>";** but it still does not send to either my outlook or gmail address.  Is there anything else that I can do?

Comment: Always post entire code to let others see what you are exactly doing. It helps in understanding the problem. Did you check in your junk folder? Do you get any error or this meassage `"Your message has been sent successfully."`

Comment: I've done it exactly as you have edited in your answer.  I've reposted exactly what I've done above.  When I test it, I get `"Your message has been sent successfully"`.  Nothing in my junk mail.  I have tested for both outlook and gmail emails

Comment: I have just run this code with your and mine email id. I received the email in my junk folder. Did you receive a copy of it? Please check. If not, then check your email address or try with other gmail id.

Comment: Yes, thanks! I received the email in my Outlook inbox.  I did not see the post come through on my MySQL table though when I checked.

Comment: Yes, because I ran email part only. I don't have the DB to execute your mysql query. Last suggestion I can give you is to put email code before `echo mysql_error();`. If doesn't work, try putting just after starting the `else{` condition

Comment: Lovely, thank you so much for all of your help!  I will give those edits a go and see if it works :D